# Problem from 'C programming a modern approach'

Tags: c

> Chapter 7 q11:
> Airline tickets are assigned lengthy identifying numbers such as 47715497443. To be valid the last digit of the number must match the remainder when the other digits - as a group - are divided by 7. Write a program to test if a ticket is valid.

My code is:

```
main(){ 

    char c;
    int remainder = 0;
    
    printf("Enter a ticket number: ");
    
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n'){
       c -= '0';
       remainder = (remainder * 10 + c) % 7;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However I cannot work out how to single out the last digit of the airline number so as to not include it in the remainder calculation and also to use it to validate the ticket.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please avoid using [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If by the value `48` you mean the ASCII specific code for the character `'0'`, use `'0'` instead (which will be correct no matter the encoding).

Comment: As for your problem, read a *string* (with e.g. `fgets`) and then you know what the last digit character will be.

Comment: By the way, reading a string solves another problem you could encounter: The [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) function returns an **`int`**, which is rather important if you want to compare the result to the `int` value `EOF`. And in a loop like yours, you really should check for `EOF` as well to handle errors or the user pressing the end-of-file keyboard sequence before you read a newline. If That happens (error or end of file) then you have an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude that helps a lot, I was only using getchar() as it was what the book suggested.

Comment: If I understand correctly *"the last digit of the number must match the remainder when the other digits - **as a group** - are divided by 7"*, you need to check if 4771549744 mod 7 == 3. Please note that 4771549744 might be too big to be stored in an `int`.

Comment: Yes that is why I was trying to deal with it one digit at a time.

Comment: So read the whole line as a string. Loop through the first len-1 characters, calculating the remainder. Then compare that with the last character.

Comment: @Bob__ The `while` loop shown is a valid algorithm for determining the remainder of any string of decimal digits, except for the noted problem of needing to stop before the last digit.

Comment: Don't assume your input comes from a user.  If you add 5 tickets into a file and redirect that input into your program (a common occurrencd), how will your current implementation behave?

Comment: You *can* use `getchar` to read character by character, but then I recommend you store it in a string anyway and don't do the calculation until you have all the digits. Or, if the number of digits is fixed and well-known then you can keep a counter in your current loop and skip the calculation for the last digit (which will then be known because of your counter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to 'buffer' the last two digits entered before the '\n'. (It may be wise to use `isdigit()` to test validity of each character typed, and to check that at least two digits have been entered.)

To 'juggle' two digits, this presumes a leading '0' (`cPrev`) has already been entered before the grinding starts. Here's a rough cut.

```
int main( void ) {
    char cPrev = '0';
    char cCurr = '0';
    int remainder = 0;

    printf( "Enter a ticket number: " );

    int cin;
    while( ( cin = getchar() ) != '\n' && cin != EOF ) {
        cPrev = cCurr;
        remainder = ( remainder * 10 + (cCurr - '0') ) % 7;
        cCurr = (char)cin;
    }
    
    if( cin != EOF )
        printf( "%s\n", remainder == cCurr - '0' ? "Valid" : "Invalid" );

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
With little else to do, here's a version that only needs 1 pending character, the evolving remainder, and an input 16bit character (for EOF). This also needs a loop counter to ensure that at least two digits are entered.

```
int main( void ) {
    for(;;) {
        char pending = '0';
        int remainder = 0;

        printf( "Enter a ticket number: " );

        int cin;
        for( int cnt = 0; ( cin = getchar() ) != '\n' && cin != EOF; cnt++ ) {
            remainder = ( remainder * 10 + (pending - '0') ) % 7;
            pending = (char)cin;
        }

        if( cin != EOF )
            printf( "%s\n", (cnt >= 2 && remainder == pending - '0') ? "Valid" : "Invalid" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should store your ticket number in a long long integer because it is lengthy! Then you should store your last digit in a variable and divide the number by 10. Finally you can check if the remainder is equal to last digit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    long long int ticketNumber;
    int lastDigit;
    int remainder;
    scanf("%lld",&ticketNumber);
    lastDigit = ticketNumber %10;
    ticketNumber/=10;
    if(ticketNumber % 7 == lastDigit){
        printf("Ticket is valid!");
    }else{
        printf("Ticket is not valid!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Given that you don't need to do math on ticket numbers, why store them as integers at all, rather than strings?

Comment: @Chris I couldn't see anything about not to use math. Is there a necessity not to use math in question?

Comment: Is the ticket number really a "number"? Or is it just a string of numeric digits?

Comment: Is it really matter? If there is no restriction, I can read the value as a string or number but I just saw his comment, 'he can only use getchar'. He didn't indicate this in question!

Comment: @CanGörkemGüneş: If the ticket number are *not too long* it does not matter much. But I have already seen ticket numbers that would not fit even in a long long. Handling such *false* numbers as strings is in fact just more robust.

Comment: But if you have no reason to expect that numbers will be greater than 2^64 = 18.44*10^18, then you can simply store the input in a 64 bit number. Both efficient and easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. I don't think its the best solution but it does work.

```
int main(void) {

char c;
int remainder = 0;
int i = 0;
char str[20] = "";

printf("Enter a ticket number: ");

while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')
{
    str[i] = c;
    i++;
}

for (int x = 0;x<i-1;x++)
{       
    remainder = (remainder * 10 + (str[x]-'0')) % 7;        
}

if (remainder == (str[i-1]-'0'))
    printf("Valid");
else
    printf("Invalid");


return 0;
```

Comment: How does this code handle a ticket number like ""? Cannot presume that the user hasn't simply pressed RETURN... That `str[ i - 1]` would be stepping out out of bounds...

Answer (score 0):

I did this question recently, and since the other answers use features that haven't been introduced in the book yet, I decided to put my solution here.

```
int main(){
      int remainder = 0, flag = 0;
      char ch;
      
      printf("Enter ticket number: ");
      
      while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
            ch -= '0';
            
            if (remainder == ch)
                  flag = 1;
            else
                  flag = 0;
            
            remainder = (remainder * 10 + ch) % 7;
      }
      
      if (flag)
            printf("VALID\n");
      else
            printf("INVALID\n");

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).